# NDK error wscicmp was not declared in this scope

Tags: android, c++, stl, android-ndk

Getting the following error:

> `wscicmp` was not declared in this scope

Android NDK's *Application.mk* contains:

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
```

*Android.mk*:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK \
                -D_STLP_HAS_WCHAR_T \
                -DDISABLE_IMPORTGL
```

Using NDK r7.

Answer (score 0):

The function `wcsicmp` is mostly a Windows-specific function. Try using the `wcscasecmp` function?

Comment: ok. well I'm on NDK R7 and tried CrystalX etc. What can be done?

Comment: I guess I would like suggestions on how to convert whar* etc

Comment: I did type def so that wstring became basic_string<wchar> but I think I need to do something more ...

Comment: See my question, how do I replace wchars